# clever way to move words at the end of the line into braces

Tags: cursor-motions

I repeatedly need to transform

```
word
```

into

```
\edlemvar{word}{}{}
```

or

```
\edlemvar{}{}{word}
```

More generally, it would be great to have a way to do this even if there are more words on the line than "word," something like `<count>COMMANDSEQUENCE` where `<count>` is however many words I would like to include in either pair of braces; the rest of the words on the line would then appear on a new line. That is, I'd like to convert (for `<count> = 2`)

```
word1 word2 word3 word4
```

to

```
\edlemvar{word1 word2}{}{} 
word3 word 4
```

or

```
\edlemvar{}{}{word1 word2} 
word3 word 4
```

**Question**: Is there some clever way in Vim/Neovim to do either this general transformation with minimal keystrokes?

I use a custom snippet that turns `edlv` into `\edlemvar{}{}{}`. But then I still need to type `Iedlv<tab><esc>$miwbp` to do the first operation, or `Iedlv<tab><esc>$miwhP` for the second --- and that's just the simple case.

Note: I use cutlass/subversive/yoink. If you don't, please replace `m` with `d`.

Comment: Maybe something like `<count>mawiedlv<tab><esc>p` or `<count>mawiedlv<tab><tab><tab><esc>p`? This almost works, but often leaves extra white space within the braces.

Comment: `"I use a custom snippet"` Care to share what snippet plugin you are using? AFAIK, most snippet engines support a visual placeholder, so that `v3iw<tab>edlv<tab>` results in `\edlemvar{word1 word2}{}{}`

Comment: I use `ultisnips`. I tried your sequence just now and it didn't work (I just got `\edlemvar{}{}{}`. Do I need to add something to the snippet to tell it where to put the portion selected in visual mode?

Comment: Yes, you need to add `$VISUAL` in your snippet. Let me post an answer to include the details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments, Ultisnips supports the use of a `$VISUAL` placeholder to include the recent visual selection in a snippet.

Instead of using <count>{motion}, use {Visual} mode to select the text to be moved inside the braces.

In the snippet definition, tell Ultisnips where to place the visually selected text (if any) with `$VISUAL`.

That is, instead of

```
snippet edlv "\edlemvar{}{}{}" 
\edlemvar{${1:one}}{${2:two}}{${3:three}}
$0
endsnippet
```

we can define

```
snippet edlv1 "\edlemvar{.}{}{}" 
\edlemvar{${1:${VISUAL:one}}}{${2:two}}{${3:three}}
$0
endsnippet
```

Now, with the text

```
word1 word2 word3 word4
```

and cursor on `word1`,
type `v3iw<tab>edlv1<tab>` to get

```
\edlemvar{word1 word2}{two}{three}
 word3 word4
```

---

*Addendum:* there is a small annoyance — a space in the start of the second line. I don't have a robust solution right now, but as a workaround, you could select the additional space at the end of word2, and use a transformation, ie.

```
snippet edlv1t "\edlemvar{.}{}{}" 
\edlemvar{${1:${VISUAL/\s+$//:one}}}{${2:two}}{${3:three}}
$0
endsnippet
```

and use `v4iw<tab>edlv1t<tab>` to get the desired result (without the leading space).